# How to associate work item with changeset (TFVC)

Tags: rest, azure-devops, tfs, tfvc, changeset

all

I want to associated work items with the changeset for [Azure DevOps Services (TFS) via REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changeset-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP).
I have been successful in creating a changeset, but if I try also to link a work item to it, nothing happened, the changeset is created without linked work item

Postman console:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=7.1-preview
{
   "changes":[
      {
         "item":{
            "path":"$/TFVCPath/archive.zip",
            "version":60404,
            "contentMetadata":{
               "encoding":-1
            }
         },
         "changeType":"edit",
         "newContent":{
            "content":"base64",
            "contentType":"base64Encoded"
         }
      }
   ],
  "workItems": [
        {
            "id": 390074,
            "assignedTo": "Roman Konrad",
            "state": "In Progress",
            "title": "Title",
            "workItemType": "task",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/390074",
            "webUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_workitems/edit/390074/"
        }
    ],
   "comment":"File from postman"
}
```

Response:
[201 created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLPS1.jpg)

I also tried different properties combination of *workItems* json object and API versions

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it, it doesn't work. As a workaround, you can call [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) rest api to associate work item with changeset (TFVC).

Once the changeset is created, you can get the `changeset ID`, then associate the work items with the changeset ID.

Below PowerShell for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://xxx/tfs/Collection", #Or the Azure DevOps organization URL
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$WorkitemID = "194",
   [string]$ChangesetID = "439",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
[
    {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "ArtifactLink",
      "url": "vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/$ChangesetID",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Fixed in Changeset"
      }
    }
  }
]

"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$($collectionurl)/_apis/wit/workitems/$($WorkitemID)?api-version=6.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Comment: Yes, as a workaround its a good solution, although it requires sending an additional request
As far as I know, a similar mechanism works for creating a check-in Visual Studio (sending changes and ability to associate wokItems to it)
Any ideas how I can do this with one request? (according API description)